# Get records with no association meeting a certain condition

Tags: ruby-on-rails, join, activerecord

Im trying to get all records (certificats) which don't have an association with a certain condition (like a specific supplier).

```
class Certificat < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :certifications
end

class Certification < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :supplier
  belongs_to :certificat
end

class Supplier < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :certifications, dependent: :destroy
end
```

My solution, but the result is always empty

```
@certificat.left_outer_joins(:certifications).where('certifications.id IS NULL AND certifications.supplier_id = ?), supplier_id)
```

Any ideas how I can retrieve ALL Certificats, which don't have an association to a specific supplier?

Answer (score 0):

After googeling and much trying!

```
Certificat.where('NOT EXISTS (SELECT id FROM certifications WHERE certifications.certificat_id = certificats.id AND certifications.supplier_id = ? LIMIT 1)', @supplier.id) %>
```